# Redirect 301 not working in Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect

I am using .htaccess to redirect a link to an external page (outside root).
however, redirect 301 is not working in Google Chrome.
but on other browsers e.g. Safari, Firefox, and IE are working.

Below is my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>


RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html


Redirect 301 /explore http://flights.skiffly.com/map/?marker=84376.map
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clear the Chrome browser's cache, and then do again?
Sometimes I got same issues, then I always clear the browser cache, and then try it again.